TYPO3 12.4 backend Login error LimitInternalRecursion
After copying a website to my local computer, the login always fails in a 500 error.
The PHP error log shows
[Tue Apr 02 16:25:24.463180 2024] 
[core:error] [pid 18408] [client 127.0.0.1:46504] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://ttproductslokal.de/typo3/

I have already added a file typo3conf/additonal.php:
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['loginRateLimit'] = 0;


After some time I have found the solution. A .htaccess file needs to be added. TYPO3 accomplishes this task in the Install Tool.
Backend Module Environment -> Directory Status
There you find this text:
**File /.htaccess does not exist
By using "Try to fix errors" we can try to create it**

Give enough write access to the public folder document root. Then press the button on the bottom of the module text. *Try to fix errors`
This will create a working .htaccess file and the backend login is possible now if you enter the correct username and password.
